# Save the choice in a dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, dropdown

I would like to ask you a question. I have this dropdown menu in a jsp page:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<div class="myBox2">
  <li class="ul"><a href="#">Αυστρία</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Βέλγιο</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Βουλγαρία</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Γαλλία</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Γερμανία</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Δανία</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ελβετία</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Εσθονία</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ηνωμένο Βασίλειο</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ιρλανδία</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ισλανδία</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ισπανία</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ιταλία</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Κύπρος</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Λετονία</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Λιθουανία</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Μάλτα</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Νορβηγία</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ολλανδία</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ουγγαρία</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Πολωνία</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Πορτογαλία</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ρουμανία</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Σλοβακία</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Σλοβενία</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Σουηδία</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Τσεχία</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Φινλανδία</a></li>
</ul>
```

And I try to find a way to save the user's choice. I want to select only one choice of the menu every time. Have you any idea?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: you want to save in client side or server side ?

Comment: in my database..because the choice is crucial in order to present the rest page (according to the choice)

Answer (score 0):

I think using radio buttons will be better if you want to store input

Answer (score 0):

You can use a select tag with the option and then with jQuery know the selected like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/gr79fv1k/

```
  <select class="myox2">
    <option>Αυστρία</option>
    <option>Βέλγιο</option>
    <option>Βουλγαρία</option>
    <option>Γαλλία</option>
    <option>Γερμανία</option>
    <option>Δανία</option>
    <option>Ελβετία</option>
    <option>Εσθονία</option>
    <option>Ηνωμένο Βασίλειο</option>
    <option>Ιρλανδία</option>
    <option>Ισλανδία</option>
    <option>Ισπανία</option>
    <option>Ιταλία</option>
    <option>Κύπρος</option>
    <option>Λετονία</option>
    <option>Λιθουανία</option>
    <option>Μάλτα</option>
    <option>Νορβηγία</option>
    <option>Ολλανδία</option>
    <option>Ουγγαρία</option>
    <option>Πολωνία</option>
    <option>Πορτογαλία</option>
    <option>Ρουμανία</option>
    <option>Σλοβακία</option>
    <option>Σλοβενία</option>
    <option>Σουηδία</option>
    <option>Τσεχία</option>
    <option>Φινλανδία</option>
  </select>
```

and the js:

```
   function selectItem() {
      alert($('.myBox2').val())
    }

    $('button').on('click', selectItem)
```

Don't forget install jQuery or you can do it with vanilla js